# Absolute difference between two consecutive number passing 3 digit as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, logical-operators

Problem statement: If we pass three digit number(121,191..) & if difference of first two consecutive no. is equal to next two consecutive number it should return true.

Below is some similar logic I am trying to build,Any help would be much helpful

```
def main():
    phrase = ("121")  
    phrase_split = phrase.split()
    for i in phrase_split:
      sum = (i[0] + i[1]) == (i[1] + i[2])
      print(sum)
main()
```

Comment: What do you mean equal to next two consecutive number?

Comment: What is you input? If it is a string, you have to split it and convert the results in to int. Since you have only three numbers, you can add first two numbers and the last two numbers. After that, you can compare them.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation of your code. In the future, please make sure that you use an *extra* four spaces in front of *each* line of the code. You can do this easily by selecting the *entire* code block and then pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: "If we pass three digit number(121,191..) & if difference of first two consecutive no. is equal to next two consecutive number it should return true." Okay, so. What operator do you use to get a *difference* between numbers?

Comment: If your teacher passes a three digit integer, you can convert it to a string. Or you can find each digit:  h = int(digit/100) t=int( (digit % 100) /10) o = digit%10

Comment: @ShivamJha : For Example: if digit is 121, we want absolute difference between first two and last two consecutive digit 1+2 = 2+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may help you, what it takes is the first and second character from the number as integer values, sum these 2 numbers and compare it with the sum of the second and third character.

I leave the code here:

```
myNumber = "121"
if (int(myNumber[0]) + int(myNumber[1]) == int(myNumber[1]) + int(myNumber[2])):
    print("true")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that there you are trying to sum up strings, try converting as a list of int first:

```
def main():
    phrase = ("121")  
    phrase_split = [int(x) for x in phrase]
    return (phrase_split[0] + phrase_split[1]) == (phrase_split[1] + phrase_split[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only three digits, just compare the first and the last.

```
num = '121'
print(num[0] == num[2])
```